# Accessing website from ip address

Tags: drupal, redirect

I've got a drupal site on dedicated server and people can access to my site from ip address.
Also google bots have had indexed some of pages.

I thought to do 301 redirect from .htacces file. Is it an efficient way?

What should I do under this situation?

Comment: What web server are you using? If it's Apache I would strongly recommend using a rewrite rule

Comment: What about indexed page with ip? Are they replace with my domain after a while?

Comment: The 301 header should do exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, instead of redirect you should use mod_rewrite (if your webserver is Apache). By adding in .htaccess something like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

you'd be telling Apache to rewrite ANY http request which finds it's way to your sites's folder in the form www.mydomain.com/ and send a 301 header to inform bots that this is the correct URL it should use.

To make this work you need to make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled in your Apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the client sends an appropriate HTTP Host header field. Redirect if it doesn't. This, of course, causes problems if the client refuses to adhere to RFC 2616.

Another option is to set up a default virtual host in Apache, that answers requests that contain no valid HTTP Host header field.

Comment: Sorry my bad english bot there is a misunderstood I think. It is a public website and everyone can visit it with two way; 1- www.mydomain.com 2-http://myip.com. I want to redirect my ip to mydomain.

Comment: That's exactly what my suggested solution does. After all, accessing http://www.example.com means, 1. the browser looks up the IP address of the host www.example.com, 2. the browser sends a HTTP request to that host, and puts `www.example.com` in the Host HTTP header field. If you access the same host using the IP address, i.e. http://192.0.43.10, the IP address 192.0.43.10 will appear in the HTTP Host header field.

Answer (score 0):

Well one way would be to ask them to change their "hosts" file if they have Windows.
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
Drag and drop "hosts" file in notepad.
Add a line like this at the end of the file:
127.0.0.1       mydedicatedsite.com
Where the number would be your ipaddress.
Save file.

Sometimes that file needs additional permissions to let you save, so just give temporary permisions to the current user or "Everyone" windows user.

You can also create a batch file that they can just execute, making things easier for them.

At the end, even if the domain doesn't exists, they will be redirected to your site with the IP specified.

Comment: Sorry my bad english bot there is a misunderstood I think. It is a public website and everyone can visit it with two way; 1- www.mydomain.com 2-http://myip.com. I want to redirect my ip to mydomain.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if you can't tell them "stop visiting my ip-address, use domain instead" then I would go with creating a Virtual host to receive all incoming traffic to your site and do redirect with .htaccess or even a simple Javascript redirect, also with this second option you can add a custom message like "Site has moved, redirecting to domain.com..."

```
<script language="javascript">alert("Site has moved, redirecting to domain.com ..."); self.location=”domain.com”;</script>
```

This will only work for users traffic.

Comment: Ok it is what I mentioned. But I couldn't understand why it happens? Why google bots indexing my ip? I want to prevent it. Do you have an idea?